# Custom Jackson deserialization causes StackOverflowError unless I add annotated interface

Tags: java, json, jackson, json-deserialization

I have to add an interceptor in Jackson at JSON deserialization that validates the constructed POJO and have access to the Json object for monitoring/logging purposes.

To achieve this I've added a simple deserializer that plainly deserializes to the POJO as follows:

```
    @Override
public T deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctx) throws IOException {
    ObjectCodec codec = p.getCodec();
    JsonNode node = codec.readTree(p);
    ABC transaction = codec.treeToValue(node, klass);
    if (ObjectUtil.hasAllFieldsNull(transaction)) {
        MonitorClient monitor = (MonitorClient) ctx.findInjectableValue("monitor", null, null);
        monitor.fireError..etc
    }
    return transaction;
}
```

I've annotated the ABC class like the following

```
@JsonDeserialize(as = ABC.class, using = ABCDeserializer.class)
class ABC {}
```

Problem with this is that it causes a StackOverflowError

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.BaseNodeDeserializer.deserializeObject(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:246) ~[?:?]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.JsonNodeDeserializer.deserialize(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:68) ~[?:?]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.JsonNodeDeserializer.deserialize(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:15) ~[?:?]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3972) ~[?:?]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readTree(ObjectMapper.java:2372) ~[?:?]
```

One way to solve this issue I found is to use the pattern for polymorphic jsons and create an interface IABC as follows

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = ABCDeserializer.class)
interface IABC {}
```

And change the definition of ABC and annotations to

```
@JsonDeserialize(as = ABC.class)
class ABC implements IABC {}
```

But I dislike this approach as I have to do this deserialization for every object we deserialize and it leads to a lot of 'useless' interfaces.

Can this be solved in a simpler way?

**Edit:**
What I ended up doing is

Add a BeanDeserializerModifier that creates a custom Deserializer which delegates to the default serializer and intercepts the json post construction:

```
public class MonitoringObjectDeserializerModifier extends BeanDeserializerModifier {

    @Override
    public JsonDeserializer<?> modifyDeserializer(DeserializationConfig config, BeanDescription beanDesc, JsonDeserializer<?> deserializer) {
        if (beanDesc.getBeanClass() == Abcd.class) {
            return new MonitoringBeanDeserializer((BeanDeserializerBase) deserializer);
        }
        return deserializer;
    }
}
```

The deserializer looks something like this:

```
public class MonitoringBeanDeserializer<T> extends BeanDeserializer {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private final JsonDeserializer<?> deserializer;

    public MonitoringBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerBase base) {
        super(base);
        this.deserializer = base;
    }

    @Override
    public T deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctx) throws IOException {
        JsonLocation initialLocation = p.getCurrentLocation();
        T transaction = ObjectUtil.uncheckedCast(deserializer.deserialize(p, ctx));
        if (ObjectUtil.hasAllFieldsNull(transaction)) {
            String txJson = extractJson(initialLocation, p.getCurrentLocation());
            MonitorClient monitor = (MonitorClient) ctx.findInjectableValue("monitor", null, null);
            monitor.abcd..
        }
        return transaction;
    }

    private static String extractJson(JsonLocation initialLocation, JsonLocation finalLocation) {
        Object source = initialLocation.getSourceRef();
        String sourceJson;
        if (source instanceof StringReader) {
            sourceJson = (String) ObjectUtil.get(source, "str");
        } else {
            sourceJson = (String) source;
        }
        int start = (int) initialLocation.getCharOffset() - 1;
        int end = (int) finalLocation.getCharOffset();
        return sourceJson.substring(start, end);
    }
}
```

No more need for annotations and other stuff. It's all a great hack, but I'd rather do this than create a lot of interfaces.

Comment: It seams that you idea completely wrong. You running deserealizer from deserealizer, it leads to your code call itself. There should be other solution for this. When you want to check your entities? Maybe during deserealization after you receive them from somewhere? If so, try to intercept them when you receive and decerialize them. Most of the framework have that option.

Comment: Or otherwise you can inherit from BeanDeserializer or something like this and do you checks after you call super method.

Comment: Basicly I want to be able to access both the Json and the deserialized value in one place, and also be able to inject some object used for monitoring the situation so that we can report the actual Json we were trying to deserialize